# How to CROSS JOIN 2 dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am struggling to get the CROSS JOIN of 2 data frame. I am using spark 2.0. How can I implement CROSSS JOIN with 2 data frame.?

Edit:

```
val df=df.join(df_t1, df("Col1")===df_t1("col")).join(df2,joinType=="cross join").where(df("col2")===df2("col2"))
```

Comment: show us what you have tried...

Comment: val df=df.join(df_t1, df("Col1")===df_t1("col")).join(df2,joinType=="cross join").where(df("col2")===df2("col2"))

Answer (score 25):

Use `crossJoin` if no condition needs to be specified

Here is an extract of working code :

```
people.crossJoin(area).show()
```

Answer (score 9):

Upgrade to latest Version of spark-sql_2.11 version 2.1.0 and use the function .crossJoin of Dataset

Answer (score 4):

Call **join** with the other dataframe without using a join condition.

Have a look at the following *example*. 
Given first dataframe of people:

```
+---+------+-------+------+
| id|  name|   mail|idArea|
+---+------+-------+------+
|  1|  Jack|j@j.com|     1|
|  2|Valery|x@v.com|     1|
|  3|  Karl|k@k.com|     2|
|  4|  Nick|n@n.com|     2|
|  5|  Luke|l@f.com|     3|
|  6| Marek|a@b.com|     3|
+---+------+-------+------+
```

and second dataframe of areas:

```
+------+--------------+
|idArea|      areaName|
+------+--------------+
|     1|Amministration|
|     2|        Public|
|     3|         Store|
+------+--------------+
```

the cross join is simply given by:

```
val cross = people.join(area)
+---+------+-------+------+------+--------------+
| id|  name|   mail|idArea|idArea|      areaName|
+---+------+-------+------+------+--------------+
|  1|  Jack|j@j.com|     1|     1|Amministration|
|  1|  Jack|j@j.com|     1|     3|         Store|
|  1|  Jack|j@j.com|     1|     2|        Public|
|  2|Valery|x@v.com|     1|     1|Amministration|
|  2|Valery|x@v.com|     1|     3|         Store|
|  2|Valery|x@v.com|     1|     2|        Public|
|  3|  Karl|k@k.com|     2|     1|Amministration|
|  3|  Karl|k@k.com|     2|     2|        Public|
|  3|  Karl|k@k.com|     2|     3|         Store|
|  4|  Nick|n@n.com|     2|     3|         Store|
|  4|  Nick|n@n.com|     2|     2|        Public|
|  4|  Nick|n@n.com|     2|     1|Amministration|
|  5|  Luke|l@f.com|     3|     2|        Public|
|  5|  Luke|l@f.com|     3|     3|         Store|
|  5|  Luke|l@f.com|     3|     1|Amministration|
|  6| Marek|a@b.com|     3|     1|Amministration|
|  6| Marek|a@b.com|     3|     2|        Public|
|  6| Marek|a@b.com|     3|     3|         Store|
+---+------+-------+------+------+--------------+
```

Comment: Dataframes now have a method named `crossJoin` for cross joining

Answer (score 2):

You might have to enable crossJoin in the spark confs.
Example:

```
spark = SparkSession
.builder
.appName("distance_matrix")
.config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled",True)
.getOrCreate()
```

and use something like this:

```
df1.join(df2, <condition>)
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment. I have a headache chasing this problem for 3 hours.

Answer (score 2):

If the areas data is small you can do it by `explode` without shuffling:

```
val df1 = Seq(
    (1,"Jack","j@j.com",1),
    (2,"Valery","x@v.com",1),
    (3,"Karl","k@k.com",2),
    (4,"Nick","n@n.com",2),
    (5,"Luke","l@f.com",3),
    (6,"Marek","a@b.com",3)
).toDF("id","name","mail","idArea")

val arr = array(
    Seq(
            (1,"Amministration"),
            (2,"Public"),
            (3,"Store")
        )
    .map(r => struct(lit(r._1).as("idArea"), lit(r._2).as("areaName"))):_*
)

val cross = df1
    .withColumn("d", explode(arr))
    .withColumn("idArea", $"d.idArea")
    .withColumn("areaName", $"d.areaName")
    .drop("d")

df1.show
cross.show
```

Output

```
+---+------+-------+------+
| id|  name|   mail|idArea|
+---+------+-------+------+
|  1|  Jack|j@j.com|     1|
|  2|Valery|x@v.com|     1|
|  3|  Karl|k@k.com|     2|
|  4|  Nick|n@n.com|     2|
|  5|  Luke|l@f.com|     3|
|  6| Marek|a@b.com|     3|
+---+------+-------+------+

+---+------+-------+------+--------------+
| id|  name|   mail|idArea|      areaName|
+---+------+-------+------+--------------+
|  1|  Jack|j@j.com|     1|Amministration|
|  1|  Jack|j@j.com|     2|        Public|
|  1|  Jack|j@j.com|     3|         Store|
|  2|Valery|x@v.com|     1|Amministration|
|  2|Valery|x@v.com|     2|        Public|
|  2|Valery|x@v.com|     3|         Store|
|  3|  Karl|k@k.com|     1|Amministration|
|  3|  Karl|k@k.com|     2|        Public|
|  3|  Karl|k@k.com|     3|         Store|
|  4|  Nick|n@n.com|     1|Amministration|
|  4|  Nick|n@n.com|     2|        Public|
|  4|  Nick|n@n.com|     3|         Store|
|  5|  Luke|l@f.com|     1|Amministration|
|  5|  Luke|l@f.com|     2|        Public|
|  5|  Luke|l@f.com|     3|         Store|
|  6| Marek|a@b.com|     1|Amministration|
|  6| Marek|a@b.com|     2|        Public|
|  6| Marek|a@b.com|     3|         Store|
+---+------+-------+------+--------------+
```