# spark join two dataframe without common column

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Need to join two dataframes in pyspark.
One dataframe  `df1` is like:

```
city  user_count_city  meeting_session
NYC    100             5
LA     200             10 
....
```

Another dataframe  `df2` is like:

```
total_user_count  total_meeting_sessions
1000               100
```

Need to calculate `user_percentage` and `meeting_session_percentage` so I need a left join, something like

```
df1 left join df2
```

How could I join the two dataframes since they do not have common key?

Take a look of solution from this post [Joining two dataframes without a common column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738694/join-two-dataframe-without-having-common-column-spark-scala)
But this is not same as my case.

Expected results

```
city user_count_city meeting_session total_user_count total_meeting_sessions
NYC    100             5                     1000     100
LA     200             10                    1000     100
....
```

Comment: i think if you add `monotonicallyIncreasingId`  and CROSS JOIN on both data frames, would this serve your purpose?

Comment: even no condition needs to be specified - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158598/how-to-cross-join-2-dataframe

Comment: what are you trying to achieve if you don't have any common column. If first Df has 5 rows and second has 2 rows what would be the output that you would expect

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for a cross join:

```
result = df1.crossJoin(df2)
```