# Carthesian product of columns in Kotlin Dataframe

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-dataframe

Is there a way to create a carthesian product (all possible pairs of values) of two columns in Kotlin [Dataframe](https://kotlin.github.io/dataframe/overview.html) (similar to [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) for Python) in form of a `DataFrame` instance?

It can naturally be achieved by converting data into native Kotlin collections and creating the product in vanilla Kotlin. But is there a Dataframe method for that?

Comment: you can create the cartesian product of two columns in a Kotlin DataFrame using the crossJoin() method.

Comment: @JaspalsinhGohil What version of the library and what class / file are you referring to? `crossJoin()` method doesn't seem to be present in the latest version 0.9.1. Neither in sources https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/dataframe/0.9.1/dataframe-0.9.1-sources.jar nor in documentation https://kotlin.github.io/dataframe/overview.html not in Github repo https://github.com/Kotlin/dataframe/search?q=crossJoin.

Comment: Use Upgrade to latest Version of spark-sql_2.11 version 2.1.0 and use the function .crossJoin of Dataset here is  link for that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158598/how-to-cross-join-2-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

[`DataFrame.fullJoin()`](https://kotlin.github.io/dataframe/join.html#join-types) computes carthesian product provided the columns have distinct names.

```kotlin
val numberColumn:DataColumn<Int> = columnOf(1, 2).rename("numbers")
val charColumn:DataColumn<String> = columnOf("a", "b").rename("chars")

val carthesianProduct:DataFrame<Any?> = numbers.toDataFrame().fullJoin(charColumn.toDataFrame())

carthesianProduct.toString()
```

```text
   numbers chars
 0       1     a
 1       1     b
 2       2     a
 3       2     b
```